# Number formatting in Sharepoint list

Tags: list, column, formatting

I have several large Sharepoint lists that I imported from Excel, the first column of each of these lists is "Customer Number" these numbers uploaded in the form 1,000,000 and so on.

I want to remove the commas from these figures. When i changed the columns to text instead of numbers in Sharepoint designer the numbers where returned in scientific notation.

Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a calculated column with the following formula should resolve your issue:

= TEXT([Customer Number], "0")